# Check if an EditText was modified

Tags: android, android-edittext

My app should open a file inside an edittext to show it to the user. If user want to modify it just press inside textwiew and write it. After do this when back button is pushed, if the text was modify, the changes should be saved, else, just close the current activity and go to parent.
There's a way to see if the text was edited?
My idea is to explicitly compare file and edittext character length, but there's something better than this "rude" method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a TextWatcher:

```
boolean changed = false;
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
    edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            changed = true;



        } 

    });
```

Just comparing the length might result in a false negative if the changes are of the same length as deletions in the text.

When the user presses back, just check if `changed` is true. This might result in a false positive if the user made an edit and then undid it, but it is better to have a few false positives than to lose user changes.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing better actually you have to compare the text and not the length. The user could just replace a word. A TextWatcher would tell you that a user is editing but he just may change and change it back. So you really need to compare strings.